# Error with button or code in VBA?

Tags: excel, button, vba

I have a some simple code that copies data, then pasts data. Then it does some small adjustments to look for a certain value and re-code it. When I hit play within the VBA editor, it does exactly what I want it to do. But when I go to click the button I have it assigned to, it copies part of the data into the correct cells, but also clears cells where data should be. I have checked the button and it says it is assigned to the correct macro. When I step through with F8 I do not have any problems. I do have other modules within the worksheet, but no other files of Excel open. Thoughts?

```
Sub Copy_Paste()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("1").Activate
    Range("A5", "a12").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Slides").Range("B14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("c5", "h12").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Slides").Range("c14").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("k18", "k20").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Slides").Range("c7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Range("e35", "m35").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Slides").Range("c26").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Slides").Activate

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("r15:r22")
        If (cell.Value = "inflatio") Then
            cell.Value = "INF"
        End If
    Next

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: "*it copies part of the data and clears another part*" is very broad... However with the information given, I'd suggest to try running the code one step at a time, go into the code and click anywhere within the segment you want to test and press `F8`, and continue pressing `F8` until you find where your logic is incorrect

Comment: I would first: Fully qualify your objects Workbook.Sheet.Range.  Don't use ActiveCell but qualify the cell Workbook.Sheet.Range(val).pasteSpecial.  When you don't qualify them they run on the worksheet that is active.

Comment: @Maldred edited. I ran through the code as suggested, everything works that way with 'F8'.

Comment: @Sorceri I see how that could be an issue, but since I am not clearing anything on the sheet and I am copying non-empty cells (I know this because I ran through it manually) I don't think declaring my objects anymore would be helpful.

Comment: @JackArmstrong doesn't matter whether it's empty cells or not, what you're referencing with that line is what you currently have as the `ActiveCell` in other words what you have selected

Comment: Not to mention, it's just good practice and you should get in the habit of it

Comment: @Maldred I see how it is not good practice. I have removed that part from my code. Any more tips?

Comment: Are you still receiving the error?

Comment: I realized I had some other code that bugged up the other stuff. It now works without any errors.